# Why declare a variable type p as new type instead of declare it just as type p?

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration

The following is a chunk of code that I am analyzing. I did not understand why the owner's code declared the variable of type **node-point** as **node *p = new node**, instead of just declare it as **node *p**. It seems to me that both approaches results in the same behavior. Am I wrong? If so, why?

```
class Queue {
    private:
        node *front;
        node *rear;
    public:
        Queue();
        ~Queue();
        bool isEmpty();
        void enqueue(int);
        int dequeue();
        void display();

};
    
void Queue::display(){
    node *p = new node;
    p = front;
    if(front == NULL){
        cout<<"\nNothing to Display\n";
    }else{
        while(p!=NULL){
            cout<<endl<<p->info;
            p = p->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, you are right. It is leaking memory by the way.

Comment: In general `node* p;` is substantially different from `node* p = new node;` (which is btw not just a declaration). However, in the code you posted `node* p = new node;` is just plain wrong

Comment: `delete` must be called with a pointer to an object that was created by `new`. The sole reference to the object created by `node *p = new node` is subsequently lost forever when the value of `p` is overwritten by `node = front`. Either `front` must be pointing to an object allocated by a separate call to `new`, or it must be equal to `nullptr` (the modern C++ equivalent of `NULL`, which is a hangover from the C programming language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that default constructing a `node` has no side-effects, the behaviour of the program is indeed the same whether you write `node *p` or `node *p = new node`, because `p` is reassigned on the very next line.

However, since the object created by `new node` is never deleted, `Queue::display` leaks memory every time it is called. It seems like you have found a bug in the code. It can probably be fixed by removing `new node` and just initializing `p` to `front`, as I suspect the author didn't really know what he was doing.

```
node *p = front;
```

Comment: @Randerson Try this, by the founder of C++ himself: [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321992784)